# Expected ratio of right-censored to non-censored waiting times in Poisson proces

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, exponential-distribution, censoring, poisson-process

I am trying to calculate the expected value of
$Y = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n min(x, X_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$, where $X_i$ are independent random variables of exponential distribution of ratio $\lambda$.

I can easily calculate $E[\sum_{i=1}^n min(x, X_i)] = \frac{n}{\lambda} (1 - e^{-\lambda x})$, and obviously $E[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i] = \frac{n}{\lambda}$.

I wonder if I am allowed to assume **from above** that $E[Y] = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$ since numerator and nominator are dependent.

I have tried to validate that assumption by performing Monte-Carlo simulations for different values of $n$ and $x$. For $n \in \{1000, 10000, 100000\}$ it seems ok, but for $n = 1$ and $x \not \gg \frac{1}{\lambda}$ $Y$ seems to be heavily underestimated.

I have also tried to calculate 
$E[\frac{min(x, X_1)}{X_1}] = 1 + e^{-\lambda x} (E[\frac{x}{x + X_1}] - 1)$, but I get stuck.

I have tried to use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20from%200%20to%20inf%20(e%5E(-y))%2F(1%20%2B%20y)%20dy) to solve $\int_0^{\inf} \frac{x}{x + y} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy$ for $\lambda = 1, x = 1$, but it returned only numerical value.

I have absolutely no idea, how can I calculate $E[Y]$ analitically.